# C++ Find and Replace String SIMPLE

Tags: c++, replace, find

I need something that will replace a text in a declared string.

Like this, but instead of Visual Basic, have it in C++

```
Dim Projectile As String = "Content"
Projectile = Replace(Projectile, "Find", "Replace")`
```

OR like this, but instead of C#, have it in C++

```
string Projectile; 
Projectile = Projectile.Replace("A", "B")
```

I need a simple code. If you can provide several options as well that would be fantastic. Also a brief explanation with the code would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What you **need** to do is pick up a book. This isn't a code writing service.

Answer (score 0):

You might find boost::algorithm::replace_all (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/boost/algorithm/replace_all.html) good for that.

Here's an example:

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
    using namespace std;
    string test = "123456";
    boost::algorithm::replace_all(test,"123","456");
    cout << test << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

will output : "456456"